# GET from api containing Key and Client from R

Tags: r, api, key, client

I need to bring data from this site (image below) in R
[image: Connect api]

but I dont know how pass the parameters Key and Client via code, can anyone help me

Follow my code:

```
dados_get <- GET('http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/72hours/temperature?idlocale=6873')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
require(httr)
require(jsonlite)

#list of parameters
a = list("key"="01234","type"="json","client"="abc","localeid"="6873")

dados_post <- POST(url='http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/monitoring/weather',
body = toJSON(a))
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I made this html code, from it works, can you tell me how to do similar in R?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4NfQ.png

Comment: @MáironChaves, the method in the HTML is ```POST``` not ```GET```.

Comment: It didn't work :( I get a message saying the user can't be authenticated ... it's weird because when I use the html I set up it works

Comment: @MáironChaves, did you add any authentication in the HTML? Or try to add the headers as per my previous answer in the ```POST``` method.